# How to implement a tiny RTSP server?

Tags: c++, rtsp

I am implementing a client/server application where video streaming occurs between two computers (in one direction). I would like to have the server publish an SDP file when it starts streaming. The client would then be able to download this SDP file and use it to get the stream. In order to implement this it seems I need to include a RTSP server in my server application.

I am planning to use either libVLC or GStreamer for the client. Both are able to get incoming video streams using the info from an SDP file.

Server-side I don't really know where to start. Can anyone recommend a good C++ library that would allow me to create a small RTSP server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Live555 LGPL library](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/) or for fun, [read the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550) and implement :-)

Comment: Thanks, I just found live555 myself.

Comment: @StackedCrooked: Can you just help me out in making live555 run on android. How did you implement that?

Comment: @Sen Sorry, but I never finished this project.

Comment: Not tiny and not the only solution

Answer (score -2):

Libcurl's library offers a simple example that can be usefull for the server side..
Take a look at: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/rtsp.html

Comment: It's great but as a rtsp client and not server.